# Check for 4 numbers and 2 letters if the first 4 characters are numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some trouble with checking for certain values and check if the value is correct.

Now I have made it work with always 4 numbers and 2 letters:

```
$("input[id='post']").keyup(function count() {
    var input = this.value;
    var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}$/i);
    console.log(regex.test(input));
});
```

This works great.

Sometimes though, my input also takes words so these words do need to go through. At the moment only 4 numbers and 2 digits are allowed.

It's basically if there is a word, so no numbers at all, I need to let that word go through.

Comment: "I have to make these words go through and not fail." - what does that mean? What are your fail/pass criteria?

Comment: You want to allow any text to go through?

Comment: Yes if there is words, so no 4 numbers at the start, I want to let that text go trhough @Craicerjack if it's a word, it needs to pass, if there are 4 numbers at the start, the remaining 2 letters need to be added.

Comment: So the criteria is any string is allowed *unless* it contains a number, then it must be `1111AA`...? Is that correct?

Comment: try `RegExp(/^([0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}|[a-z]*)$/i)`

Comment: You can also try this: RegExp(/^([0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}|[a-zA-Z_ ]*)$). It allows for multiple words to pass

Comment: Thanks @revy that was the final working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your regex as below and try like below

```
$("input[id='post']").keyup(function count() {
    var input = this.value;
    var regex = new RegExp(/^([0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}|[a-z]*)$/i);
    console.log(regex.test(input));
});
```